# How can I check a certain type is already defined in C compiler?

Tags: c, types, typedef, c-preprocessor

If a compiler has a certain type (ex. ptrdiff_t) as an embedded type, I don't want to typedef it again. I know that below code does not work properly that I expected.

```
#ifndef ptrdiff_t 
    typedef long int ptrdiff_t;
#endif
```

How can I check a certain type is already defined in the **C** compiler?

Comment: In your particular case.  ptrdiff_t should always be defined if you include stddef.h

Comment: Being able to test in code for the existence and properties of particular definitions is called "reflection". Scripting languages tend to support full reflection, partly because it's relatively easy for scripting languages. .NET and the JVM support reflection too. For native languages, however, supporting run-time reflection would require a lot of extra executable code. Some compile-time reflection can be supported without that overhead, but C has virtually no reflection support even at compile-time.

Comment: Use a tool like cmake or autotools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you are a bit confusing 2 different things:

There are built in types, like `int`, `float`, etc. These are standard types and they are defined is all compilers. Types like `__int64` were introduced and standardized later. This means that they are defined in all recent compilers but only in some of the older compilers. You do not need to do anything to use them. At the same time you cannot figure out in your code if they are defined or not. This can be figured out only from the docs on the compiler. You can write:

```
#ifdef MSVC
       .... Microsoft specific code
#else
       .... Code for other compiler.
#endif
```

This approach allows you to create sort of `compiler independent environment`.

Besides the built in types, there are types that come from the headers. Some headers have constructs like:

```
#ifndef ptrdiff_t_DEFINED
    #define ptrdiff_t_DEFINED
    typedef long int ptrdiff_t;
#endif
```

Note that the macro-processor definitions stay apart from the definition of the type. You cannot check if the type is defined or not, but you can easily check if a macro definition is defined.

What headers are included in your code you deside yourself. This means that these definitions are not `in the compiler itself`. They are in the set of definitions of the current translation unit. For compiler they have little difference from other type definitions that you write in your own code.

Some compiler or system headers for not have "guarding defns" like in the example above. In this case the only thing that you can do is to track from what headers thay are coming and include/not include these headers, maby using your own `#ifdef` guards around the `#include` statements.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, there is no good general solution to this. Type names are not visible to the preprocessor, so you can't use `#ifdef` to test for their existence.

There are a number of partial solutions, though, and they vary depending on where the requirements for a given type came from.

There are several versions of the ISO C standard, issued in 1990, 1999, and 2011. Each new standard (in theory) supersedes and replaces the previous one, and each one defines some new types. For example the 1999 C standard added headers `<stdbool.h>` and `<stdint.h>`, and types `bool`,  `int32_t`, etc. If you want to use the `bool` type, but still want your code to be portable to implementations that don't support C99, you can do something like:

```
#if defined(__STDC__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#include <stdbool.h>
#else
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
#endif
```

The `enum` type doesn't behave *exactly* like C99's built-in `bool` type, so you need to be a little careful in how you use it.

The type `uintptr_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>` is optional. It's an unsigned type that can hold a converted `void*` pointer value without loss of information; an implementation that has no such unsigned type (say, because pointers are bigger than any integer type) won't provide it. You can't directly test for the type itself, but you can test for the macros that give its bounds:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef UINTMAX_MAX
/* uintmax_t exists */
#else
/* uintmax_t doesn't exist */
#endif
```

You may need to wrap this in a test for `__STDC__` and `__STDC_VERSION__` if you can't assume C99 or better.

The type `long long` is a predefined type (not part of the library), added in C99. Again, you can't test for it directly, but you can test for the macros that define its bounds:

```
#include <limits.h>

#ifdef LLONG_MAX
/* long long exists */
#else
/* long long *probably* doesn't exist */
#endif
```

Finally, there are things you can't do directly in C, but that you can do as part of your program's build process. For example, POSIX defines a type `pid_t` in the POSIX-specific header `<unistd.h>` (it's the type of a process identifier, returned by the `getpid()` function). You can't conditionally include a header -- but you can write a small program that will fail to compile if the header doesn't exist:

```
#include <unistd.h>
pid_t dummy;
```

As part of your build process, try to compile this file. If it succeeds, append a line like

```
#define HAVE_PID_T
```

to a configuration header; if it fails, append a line like

```
#undef HAVE_PID_T
```

In your source code, you can then write something like:

```
#include "config.h"
#ifdef HAVE_PID_T
#include <unistd.h>
/* pid_t exists */
#else
/* pid_t doesn't exist */
#endif
```

[GNU Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) provides a way to automate this kind of test, but it's been criticized for being overly complex and unwieldy.

All of this assumes that, once you've determined whether a type exists, you can do something useful with that information. For some types, like `bool`, you can implement a nearly equivalent alternative. For `pid_t`, on the other hand, there likely isn't a good fallback, unless you simply `#ifdef` out all the code that deals with processes. If your program just isn't going to work on a system that doesn't have `pid_t` and `getpid()`, it might be best to just write code that assumes they exist. If you try to compile your code on a system that doesn't provide them, it will immediately fail to compile, and that may be the best thing you can do.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to do that in general.  In some cases there may be a macro that is defined at the same time as the type that you can use.

In your particular example, you can `#include <stddef.h>`, which should always define ptrdiff_t.

Answer (score 0):

Since redefining a C language reserved construct would generally lead to a compile time error, it is not possible to check it in general. 
If you are interested(for academic/learning process), you can write a basic compiler pass to check for exceptions/errors on your C program to detect if a type is reserved or not.